# How to restart my dev django sqlite + create admin user in one command?

Tags: django, sqlite, admin

This is intended as a community wiki question, after going through the hardship of resetting my django migrations.
The main problem was -> resetting the migrations. the other stuff is easy.

So, how do you reset your django table, when you're just starting to develop and make frequent changes to your models?

Answer (score 0):

Simple.
Create a batch/bash file (I gave the windows batch but the bash shouldn't be that different) and name it mig.bat and put it in your main project's folder.

Notice you need only to change the app_name to the name of your app (mine's feeder). Then, every time you want to re-create your sqlite+migrations+superuser(admin) you just need to run "mig" and restart your server.

```
set app_name=feeder

del /Q /S db.sqlite3
del /Q /S .\%app_name%\migrations\*.*
python manage.py makemigrations %app_name%
python manage.py migrate
echo from django.contrib.auth.models import User; User.objects.create_superuser('admin', 'admin@example.com', '1234qwer1234') | python manage.py shell
```